# Quartiles with many zeroes

Tags: probability

I am trying to evaluate a data set with 194 columns where there are many zeroes for several variables. 
Namely, variable a: 85 zeroes, variable b: 81 zeroes and variable c: 114 zeroes.

My question is now, WHETHER I CAN IGNORE THOSE ZEROES in the calculation of quartiles or whether it would give a more meaningful result if the zeroes were included in the calculation (even though for e.g. c that would mean more than 50 % zeroes!!!).

For example: imagine having ten values: 0,1,4,6,0,0,8,9,0,0. Including zeroes would mean that Q1 <= 0; 0 < Q2 < 0.5; 0.5 < Q3 < 6.5. Excluding zeroes would mean that Q1 <= 2.5; 2.5 < Q2 < 6 ; 6 < Q3 < 8.5. Both are possible - which is more correct?

:)
Thanks for your help!!

Comment: The question is a little unclear but why won't you try it and find out?

Comment: hm I'll try to make it more clear: imagine having ten values:

Comment: Add it to your original post.

Comment: **You can't get rid of data.** But that really depends *what* the data is for. What are you analyzing the statistics for?

Comment: energy potential in all 194 UN member states

Comment: I don't really know what this means but it sounds like a case where you can't take the zeros out if you plan to include *all* the UN member states. If you want to make your data only about the UN member states that *have* energy potential, then you can remove the zeros. If you have a specific request it'd be easier to help you determine.

Answer (score 3):

To decide whether to ignore the zeros, you have to know what the zeros mean.

For example, maybe the zeros mean "information not available", and do not really mean that the value is zero.  For example, maybe the values are temperatures, but your table contains "0" when the temperature was not measured.  In that case it would not make sense to include them in the quartiles.

On the other hand, maybe the zero values really mean a result of zero.  For example, maybe the numbers are reporting how many times a certain thing happened, and the zeros indicate the cases where it happened zero times.  In this case you should include the zeros in your analysis.